# Permission to add user to db_accessadmin without adding to db_owner

Tags: sql, permissions, azure-sql-database

I have a client with a head-office, and various field offices.

I would like to grant a couple of head office people, who are SQL Azure contained users, the permission be become an "admin-lite". Specifically, I want them to be able to be able to create users, and make them in/active (with GRANT or REVOKE CONNECT).

I'd also like them to be able to assign other people to this same "admin-lite" role - they can then nominate one person in each branch who can create and manage their own users (there's quite a high turnover of staff).

The way I've made the first of the Head Office "admin-lites" is by making them a member of these two roles:

- db_accessadmin - so they can create new users and issue GRANT or REVOKE CONNECT statements
- db_securityadmin  - so they can assign the new user to the appropriate role

Incidentally, they only need to be able to assign standard users to is a custom role, not a built-in role.

However, I've been able to make the first of these Head Office "admin-lites" because I'm a member of db_owners. As mentioned, I'd like them to be able to the same for their field offices - but I don't want to make the Head Office admin a member of db_owners, because this also gives them permission to make anyone else a db_owner too.

So, the question is, can I create a custom role with the permission to add people to db_accessadmin and db_securityadmin without them being a db_owner? Can I create a custom role with the same permissions as db_accessadmin and db_security admin that makes this easier, perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you want to create a role which mimics the same functionality as db_accessadmin + db_securityadmin combined, but at the same time you do not want the members to be a member of db_owner.

Here is a role called FieldOfficeAdmin that does the same.

```
CREATE ROLE FieldOfficeAdmin 
    
 /* db_accessadmin permissions */
 GRANT CONNECT to FieldOfficeAdmin ;  
 GRANT ALTER ANY USER to FieldOfficeAdmin ;  
    
 /* db_securityadmin permissions */
 GRANT CREATE SCHEMA to FieldOfficeAdmin ;  
 GRANT ALTER ANY ROLE to FieldOfficeAdmin ;  
 GRANT CREATE ROLE to FieldOfficeAdmin ;  
 GRANT ALTER ANY APPLICATION ROLE to  FieldOfficeAdmin ;  
 GRANT VIEW DEFINITION to FieldOfficeAdmin ;
```

Add any user(s) to this role, they will further be able to create more users and add them as members to the same role

```
 CREATE USER fieldofficeadmin1 WITH PASSWORD = 'enterStrongPassword@1234';
 GO
    
 ALTER ROLE FieldOfficeAdmin ADD MEMBER fieldofficeadmin1
```

When you login as fieldofficeadmin1, you will be able to create more users and add them to the role

```
 CREATE USER fieldofficeadmin2 WITH PASSWORD = 'enterStrongPassword@1234';
 GO
    
 ALTER ROLE FieldOfficeAdmin ADD MEMBER fieldofficeadmin2
```

But when you login as fieldofficeadmin1 and try to add a member to db_owner

```
 ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER FieldOfficeAdmin2
```

It should fail with the below error

```
 Failed to execute query. Error: Cannot add the principal 'FieldOfficeAdmin2', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Please let me know if you have any further questions or if I interpreted your requirement incorrectly.